# CIFilter won't apply filter at touch location

Tags: ios, swift, image, imageview, cifilter

I am using the code below to apply an image filter to a touch location with a set radius, but the filter is being placed in the wrong spot. The x coordinate seems to be close, but the y coordinate is reversed and 400+ pixels off from my touch. If I move my finger up, the filter moves down and the opposite. Am I using the kCIInputCenterKey : CIVector parameter incorrectly? How do I place the center of my filter radius at my touch location?

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPixellate")!
    let inputImage = CIImage(image: originalImage)!
    filter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    let fullPixellatedImage = filter.outputImage
    var maskImage: CIImage!
    let radialGradient = CIFilter(name: "CIRadialGradient",
        withInputParameters: [
            "inputRadius0" : 30,
            kCIInputCenterKey : CIVector(x: (touches.first?.locationInView(self.view).x)!, y: (touches.first?.locationInView(self.view).y)!)
        ])!
    let radialGradientOutputImage = radialGradient.outputImage!.imageByCroppingToRect(inputImage.extent)
    if maskImage == nil {
        maskImage = radialGradientOutputImage
    } else {
        maskImage = CIFilter(name: "CISourceOverCompositing",
            withInputParameters: [
                kCIInputImageKey : radialGradientOutputImage,
                kCIInputBackgroundImageKey : maskImage
            ])!.outputImage
    }
    let blendFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIBlendWithMask")!
    blendFilter.setValue(fullPixellatedImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    blendFilter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputBackgroundImageKey)
    blendFilter.setValue(maskImage, forKey: kCIInputMaskImageKey)
    let blendOutputImage = blendFilter.outputImage!
    let blendCGImage = context.createCGImage(blendOutputImage, fromRect: blendOutputImage.extent)
    mainImageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: blendCGImage)

}
```